# Recyclerview updating all viewholders

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that has multiple view types. Basically, onclick button, I want to loop through all of the recyclerview's children (including viewholders not visible on the screen) and save it to Firebase. Then later on, I want to grab that information from Firebase and repopulate my recyclerview with that data. How would I go about this? My issue is that calling getChildCount() on recyclerview only gets the visible children on the screen. However, I need all children. Am I going about this the right way? Or should I be populating my viewholders with data as it is being shown on the screen?

Code for clarification

This is what I'm using to get the data so that I can insert it into Firebase

```
int numberOfViews = displayWorkoutAdapter.rowTypeList.size() - 1;
                                    Log.d("numberOfViews", String.format("%s", numberOfViews));
                                    for (int a = 0; a < numberOfViews; a++) {
                                        RowType rowType = displayWorkoutAdapter.rowTypeList.get(a);
                                        Log.d("rowTypeClass", rowType.getClass().toString());

                                        if (rowType.getClass() == ExerciseModel.class) {
                                            ExerciseModel exerciseModel = (ExerciseModel) rowType;
                                            String exerciseString = exerciseModel.getExercise();
                                            String weightString = exerciseModel.getWeight();
                                            String setString = exerciseModel.getSets();
                                            String repsString = exerciseModel.getReps();
                                            Log.d("exerciseString", exerciseString);


                                            insertDataToTable(tableName, exerciseView, null, exerciseString, weightString, setString, repsString, null, null, "0");

                                        }
```

OnBindViewHolder

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position){

    if(holder instanceof ExerciseRowHolder) {
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).exercise.setText(((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(position)).getExercise());
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).weight.setText(((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(position)).getWeight());
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).set.setText(((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(position)).getSets());
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).rep.setText(((ExerciseModel) rowTypeList.get(position)).getReps());
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).dragHandle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).exercise.setAdapter(getExerciseAdapter(home.getContext()));
    }
```

ExerciseRowHolder class

```
    public static class ExerciseRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView dragHandle;
    public EditText weight;
    public EditText set;
    public EditText rep;
    public AutoCompleteTextView exercise;
    public ExerciseRowTextListener exerciseRowTextListener;

    public ExerciseRowHolder(View view, ExerciseRowTextListener exerciseRowTextListener){
        super(view);

        dragHandle = view.findViewById(R.id.reorder);
        weight = view.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        set = view.findViewById(R.id.sets);
        rep = view.findViewById(R.id.reps);
        exercise = view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);


    }
}
```

Comment: You have an adapter, **this** is your data. Never use ViewHolders to store anything out of adapter. So, simply iterate adapter.

Comment: How would you assign a view at a position in the adapter? Would I use getItemViewType? Or should I create a method in the adapter that will return the view? Also, in my adapter, I have a List<RowType> rowTypeList called. This is where I'm putting my data. So should I be iterating through this List instead?

Comment: In your overridden `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` you have a `viewType` argument. Based on its value you creating viewHolder. Next in `onBindViewHolder` you may bind data to view based on its type got by `getItemViewType(position)`. It's hard to explain in comment, better refer on RecyclerView documentation.

Comment: I have a better understanding of it now. However, I'm still confused as to how I'm going to set my data. For example, how would I get the value of an edittext in a viewholder, when I click a button so that I can set that value to a model.

Comment: Button clicked, so you know the position. Then, modify adapter: `adapter.get(position).postMyAwesomeChanges(...)`. And tell RecyclerView about your changes: `notifyItemChanged(position)`.  Read the manual.

Comment: This only works for the views that are currently visible correct? If so, would a better implementation of this be to save the data using a textWatcher?

Comment: This works for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your data in adapter instead of viewholder, see: [RecyclerView Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

1.

> onclick button, I want to loop through all of the recyclerview's children (including viewholders not visible on the screen) and save it to Firebase.

To loop through all the recyclerview's data, instead of using `recyclerview.getChildCount()`, use `adapter.getItemCount()`.

2. > Then later on, I want to grab that information from Firebase and repopulate my recyclerview with that data. How would I go about this?

After you gets all the data from firebase, store your data in your adapter. and then use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

---

Example:

Your adapter:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseRowHolder.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ExerciseModel> mData;

    public AppPickerGridListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<ExerciseModel> apps) {
        mData = apps;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = (View) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_view_layout, parent, false);
        
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ...
        ExerciseRowHolder vh = new ExerciseRowHolder(v, exerciseRowHolderListener);
        vh.dragHandle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExerciseModel item = mData.get(position);
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).exercise.setText(item.getExercise());
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).weight.setText(item.getWeight());
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).set.setText(item.getSets());
        ((ExerciseRowHolder) holder).rep.setText(item.getReps());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public ExerciseModel getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    public ArrayList<ExerciseModel> getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<ExerciseModel> data) {
        mDatamData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Your Activity after your save button clicked:

```
ArrayList<ExerciseModel> data = mAdapter.getData();
// save this data to firebase
```

After you get your data from firebase:

```
ArrayList<ExcerciseModal> data = getFirebaseData();
mAdapter.setData(data);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped a lot. So if I'm understanding this correctly, anytime I need to update data, the adapter should be used to update the List that is associated with holding the data, instead of editing the List directly, correct? I guess either way would achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is the method in activity which changes all the data...you can perform all firebase operation in your activity and then you can call this method..this will update all the data.

Comment: I am calling this method. The issue is getting all the edittext values. When I click save, I'm looping through the List that contains all my data. However, the data is returning null, and I believe this is because the data hasn't been set, which is why I'm wondering where I should set it

Comment: After I click save?

Comment: When you are setting value of a textView...then just after that add it to a list also...that list can be used everywhere..using interface...so your work can be done easily...by iterating over the list and getting all children value

Comment: I'm using an Edittext. So the value could be anything. I've added code snippets to help you understand my situation better